# How to delete directory ~/Pictures?

Tags: permission, filesystem, folders, macos

This is on MacOS Catalina, but the same behavior has been observed in prior versions of MacOS.

Similar questions have been asked for other default directories in the default home directory, but this is different. I am able to delete most of the other directories: `~/Music`, `~/Public`, and `~/Movies` all went away after I removed any ACL's from them. But `~/Pictures` is different, and no matter what I do, MacOS refuses to delete it.

```
bash-5.0# /bin/ls -led Pictures
drwxrwxr-x  2 MyLogin  MyGroup  64 Nov  5 18:17 Pictures
bash-5.0# /bin/ls -lea Pictures
total 0
drwxrwxr-x   2 MyLogin  MyGroup    64 Nov  5 18:17 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 72 MyLogin  MyGroup  2304 Nov  5 18:17 ..
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Note that the last ACL is applied to the parent directory of `~/Pictures` ie. my home directory, and that is not the cause of this behavior as I am able to delete other subdirectories without trouble.

This also does not appear to be a restriction imposed by System Integrity Protection:

```
bash-5.0# /bin/ls -leOd /usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x  1014 root  wheel  restricted 32448 Oct 23 01:19 /usr/bin
bash-5.0# /bin/ls -leOd Pictures/
drwxrwxr-x  2 MyLogin  MyGroup  - 64 Nov  5 18:23 Pictures/
bash-5.0# /bin/ls -leOa Pictures/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x   2 MyLogin  MyGroup  -   64 Nov  5 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 72 MyLogin  MyGroup  - 2304 Nov  5 18:23 ..
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Note the `restricted` attribute on `/usr/bin` which *is* protected by SIP. `~/Pictures` has no such attribute.

I've tried as root, as my normal user account, and even as a different user after setting the permission 777. Nothing works.

My question is: what is protecting `~/Pictures` from deletion, and how can I turn it off?

Comment: Not to be flip but macOS is protecting it. you update macOS and it (and most of the others) will all come back. Apple *has decreed* (gah...) that certain userland directories Shall Not Be Deleted. Which brings to mind "tilting at windmills" or "you can't fight city hall."

Comment: @SteveChambers clearly macOS is protecting it. I actually set up a cron job to keep deleting them if they come back, and which runs much more often than the re-spawn (I just hate them that much). So one might say i have vanquished the windmills and stuck it to city hall for 3 out of 4 tries, but this last one is a real pest.

Comment: @Z4-tier Have you tried with SIP disabled? I know you say it doesn't *look* like it's protected by SIP, but it also doesn't *look* like there's anything else preventing its deletion, and yet here we are. Worth a try!

Comment: You can delete it while in **macOS Recovery**, without disabling **SIP**.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, it is protected by **SIP**, however, as is already said, it can be deleted while in **macOS Recovery** without disabling **SIP**.

Comment: @user3439894 It's up to OP, but they currently have a cron job that auto-deletes the folder if it's restored by an update. That won't work if SIP is on.

Comment: Are you using Photos?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I have not tried it with SIP disabled, I will give that a try. My only concern is that I would need to either permanently disable SIP, or reboot into recovery console every time I want to delete the folder. Neither option is very appealing.

Comment: @Allan I am not using Photos.

Comment: Have you used it before?  Even for a moment when you opened it and closed it?  Do you use *any* utility that accepts pictures (AirDrop, etc.) that might have the Pictures directory configured?  SIP doesn't protect users folders, but the OS and/or apps will recreate it so things don't sideways when the directory can't be found.

Comment: @Allan I may have opened a program that uses it at some point. I know I don't regularly use any program that would need it, but can't be certain that I've *never* opened such a program at any point. I am aware that the OS will sporadically decide to recreate it, but what is odd is that no user at all is able to even delete it, regardless of what permissions are set and what apps are actually running at that moment. This is not being treated like a normal directory on a UNIX-like OS, something else (SIP apparently) is interfering.

Comment: @Allan, It doesn't matter. I've tested on a clean install of **macOS Catalina** and even after removing the **ACL** on **Photos Library.photoslibrary** and deleting it, **Pictures** still cannot be deleted. The only way that worked for me is what's expressed in my answer to the OP.

Comment: [SIP doesn't protect user folders](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).  I'm not at my Mac at the moment, but I'll have a look.  I seem to remember deleting this before (prior to Catalina) but after SIP was introduced.  Out of curiosity...why the need to remove it?

Comment: @Allan, Aside from what that article states, the proof is in the pudding! **~/Pictures** is not directly delete-able by the User unless done from **macOS Recovery** or from a _normal mode boot_ with **SIP** disabled! So AFAIC whether or not **Apple** officially states it, **~/Pictures**, whether directly or indirectly and aside from **ACL**'s, is being protected in some way by **SIP**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: what is protecting ~/Pictures from deletion, and how can I turn it off?

In **macOS Catalina** the **Users** > **$USER** > **Pictures** folder, aside from **ACL**'s set on it, it is being protected by **System Integrity Protection** (**SIP**).

Even using `sudo chmod -N Pictures`, while in the **Home** *directory* in **Terminal**, the *directory* **can not** be deleted unless done from **macOS Recovery** using **Terminal** without turning off **SIP**.

- **Caution**: This will remove the **Pictures** *directory* and everything in it!

Example:

```
rm -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/name/Pictures"
```

- Replacing `name` in `/name/` with your *short name*, the name of your **Home** *directory*.
- Replacing `Macintosh HD` as appropriate if you've modified the *default name*.

If you want to be able to delete if from a normal running occurrence of **macOS Catalina**, not **macOS Recovery**, then you will need to turn off **SIP** from **macOS Recovery** using **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu.

```
csrutil disable
```

You could then immediately use:

```
csrutil enable --without fs
```

This way, except for the *filesystem*, the other protections offered by **SIP** are still in play.

Personally, I do not recommend doing this and would opt for deleting it from **macOS Recovery** without turning off **SIP** and then once booted back to normal mode **macOS Catalina**... I'd create the *directory* from **Terminal** while setting it *hidden* with `SetFile`, applying **ACL**'s to prevent any modifications while also removing all normal privileges (`rwx`), all in the hope that **Apple** doesn't mess with it until the next upgrade.

That said, if your are the type that always shows all *files* including the *hidden* ones, then what's mentioned in the paragraph above is a moot point.

---

**Notes**:

To boot to **macOS Recovery** from a running occurrence, *normal mode boot*, of **macOS**, you can use the following *compound command* from **Terminal**:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sleep 2; sudo reboot
```

Then before rebooting from **macOS Recovery**, in **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu, run:

```
nvram -d recovery-boot-mode
```

The latter is not necessary in some versions of macOS, however, it doesn't hurt either way.

Comment: But shouldn't `ls -lO` (two bad letters: lowercase "Lima", uppercase "Oscar") show this directory as `Restricted` the same as `/usr/bin`? My understanding is that the restricted flag indicates that SIP file system protection is enabled for that path, but maybe I am wrong about that?

Comment: @Z4-tier, One would think so, however, the only way I was able to delete it was from **macOS Recovery** without disabling **SIP** or from a _normal mode boot_ after disabling **SIP**. So what I've presented does indeed answer the question asked and quoted in my answer.

Comment: Let me give it a try and see if it works, and if so then I will accept this answer and open a follow-up asking about the "Restricted" attribute, what it actually means (apparently not what I assumed, and what I would expect most people would also assume). What is even more bizarre, I can't `chown` any of the contents of `/usr/bin` even as root (presumably due to SIP), but `~/Pictures` has no such restrictions...

Comment: @Z4-tier, `/usr/bin` in **macOS Catalina** is on a _read-only_ volume and why, from a _normal mode boot_ it cannot be modified without both disabling **SIP** and remounting `/` as _read-write_.

Comment: Ohh yes, I forgot about Apple's latest nanny security scheme with these being mounted read-only. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Give 'Full Disk Access' to the terminal by going to **Settings** ► **Privacy & Security** ► **Full Disk Access** and then running

```
sudo rm -rf Pictures
```

removes it.

Tried in mac Sonoma 14.2

Comment: I just updated to Sonoma so I will give this a try. Note that this question originally was targeted toward Catalina, and this solution is confirmed to *not work* on that version, so Apple must have changed something.